# Updating SQL Database Table with 30M Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a MS SQL table with approx 30M rows that I need to update a field based on the previous records.  Here is an update that works but it is taking an incredible amount of time:

```
UPDATE AccountTransaction
SET EndingBalance = (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(b.amount), 0)
FROM AccountTransaction AS b
WHERE b.AccountId = AccountTransaction.AccountId 
and b.Date <= AccountTransaction.Date 
and (b.Date != AccountTransaction.Date 
     or b.CreatedDate < AccountTransaction.CreatedDate)) 
+ Amount
```

Here is the full DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccountTransaction](
    [AccountTransactionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](16, 2) NOT NULL,
    [EndingBalance] [decimal](16, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PkAccountTransaction] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AccountTransactionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IxAccountTransaction_AccountId_Date_CreatedDate] ON [dbo].[AccountTransaction]
(
    [AccountId] ASC,
    [Date] ASC,
    [CreatedDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([AccountTransactionId],
    [Amount],
    [EndingBalance]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IxAccountTransaction_AccountId] ON [dbo].[AccountTransaction]
(
    [AccountId] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([AccountTransactionId],
    [Amount],
    [EndingBalance],
    [Date],
    [CreatedDate]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: There is no table (or alias) `AccountTransaction` in your query.

Comment: how many distinct `Table1Id` are there in those 30M rows?

Comment: You are updating `table1`, using a subquery that sums amount from `table1` but joined on `table1id`, if `table1id` is unique and is only referencing the same row, why are you using a subquery? and how can `b.createddate` be less than `table1.createddate` or `b.date!=table1.date` if they are referencing the same row?

Comment: Try to build 2 queries. Probably OR kills your performence a lot.

Comment: Your query resolves to `update table1 set EndingAmount = Amount` if `table1Id` is unique.

Comment: I've got you guys all over the place, my appologies.  Table1.Table1Id is not the primary key.  There could be anywhere between 0 and 1000 records with the same Table1Id.

Comment: Add actual table DDL and indexes so we know what we're looking at please.

Comment: DDL added to original post.

Comment: Can you please review the query? I edited the post for readability, and there appears to be a spare "+ amount" at the end. Also, please post an EXPLAIN.

Comment: the + amount is proper.  I'm trying to sum the amount column for all the records previous to this one, based on the same accountid and then add the amount of this record to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

The following should yield much better performance and will be able to take advantage of the IxAccountTransaction_AccountId_Date_CreatedDate index...

```
WITH 
    cte_Runningtotal AS (
    SELECT 
        at1.EndingBalance, 
        NewEB = SUM(at1.Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY at1.AccountId ORDER BY at1.[Date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM
        dbo.AccountTransaction at1
    )
UPDATE rt SET 
    rt.EndingBalance = rt.NewEB
FROM
    cte_Runningtotal rt;
```